# Smallest 3x3 Magic Square of different square sums

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, optimization, number-theory, magic-square

Consider the follow magic square highlighted in yellow. The sum of its rows and columns are in green and the sum of the diagonals in red.
All of its sums are a square number with the sum of the whole square also being a square number.

[image: Magic Square of Different Square Sums]

The above square has a repeated sum in one each of the diagonal and one row and one column.

**question 1**
What is the smallest set numbers that you can put into a 3x3 grid so ALL 8 of its sums are all different square numbers and the sum of the whole also being a square number?

**question 2**
Using triangle numbers instead of square numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45,......... and so on
What is the smallest set of number to result in all of its sums being triangle numbers with the sum of the whole also being a triangle number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**answer 1** (square sums)

> [image]

This is the smallest because...

> 441 is the smallest square that is the sum of three distinct squares in two non-intersecting ways. This solution also has the lowest possible maximum value of 157.

**answer 2** (triangular sums)

> [image]

This is smallest because...

> Isn't it obvious?

Comment: _...is the smallest square that is the sum of three distinct squares in two non-intersecting ways._ How do you know this? (I know because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) knows.)

Comment: @loopywalt Interesting. I computed, via code, all sums of three distinct squares less than 1000, essentially generating the data shown on that page.

Comment: The triangle solution has a cell of 34. Is there another solution that uses the smallest numbers  to populte the grid

Comment: @Maff If you allow one of the numbers to be zero, then a solution with a maximum of 26 is possible.

Comment: Does that mean there are no other versions of the triangular square that have solutions.

Comment: Say for example putting the 6 across the top row. Or putting 2 in the middle

Comment: @Maff Except for a slight variation, the solution I presented is the only solution with a sum of 91 that does not include a zero in the grid. No solutions exist with a lesser sum.

Comment: I mean instead of having 34 and 14 in the grid would it be possible to reduce the highest value in the grid by say reducing the 34 to 32 and increasing 14 to 16 the overall sum would remain 91 but the highest value within the grid has been reduced. Is 34 the lowest that the highest value within the grid can be

Comment: @Maff See updated solutions.

Comment: The highest entry on the square numbers grid dropped quite drastically....if the overall total of the grid being a square itself is ignored then is it possible to construct a grid that has consecutive square numbers for all 8 of its sum. 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81 and 100? With the lowest values possible being entered into the grid

Comment: @Maff Yes, it is possible: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpefJ.png)